# Как настроить фильтр поиска после смены темы?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины, themes

Приобрел тему Motors - Car Dealer and Rental, установил её. На главной странице есть фильтр, который работает благодаря заданным категориям и атрибутам.
http://ybex.com/d/tk5i9pcedi25bj6thiqcwririva0rvx96fm2n5zy.html
Проблема заключается в том, что этот фильтр работает благодаря листингу. То есть в самой теме уже изначально было создано несколько категорий листинга, которые и выводятся в этот фильтр, а категории с атрибутами woocommerce в этом фильтре не фигурируют. Как можно сделать так, чтобы в фильтре можно было искать товар благодаря атрибутам wc, а не листинга.
Вроде бы есть специальные плагины, но не получилось их найти, к сожалению.

Answer (score 1):

Реализовать поиск по атрибутам в целом просто. Атрибуты это термины, пример выборки:

```
$args = [
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'post_type'      => [ 'product', 'product_variation' ], // Не забудь product_variation
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'tax_query'      => [
        'relation' => 'AND',
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'pa_quantity', //Слаг атрибута
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => '67', //ID атрибута
        ],
    ],       
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: В результате этого в фильтре будут отображаться атрибуты wc? Если да, то не могли бы вы подсказать, в какой раздел необходимо этот код вставить?

Comment: Это не фильтр, а пример выборки для поиска по атрибутам. Фильтр - это просто обычная форма. Отправляете форму куда-то и обрабатываете на бэке похожей выборкой